# Docker service start failed

Tags: docker, centos7

I have a CentOS 7.2 VM with Docker installed. Docker service and Docker container worked normally previously. But when I tried to pull a docker image, the VM was shutdown abruptly. After I restarted the VM, the Docker service could not be started:

```
[root@AY13091717064020986bZ ~]# service docker start
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start  docker.service
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

`systemctl status docker.service` output:

```
[root@AY13091717064020986bZ ~]# systemctl status docker.service
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; disabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-08-23 19:11:19 CST; 13min ago
     Docs: http://docs.docker.com
  Process: 1404 ExecStart=/usr/bin/docker-current daemon --exec-opt native.cgroupdriver=systemd $OPTIONS $DOCKER_STORAGE_OPTIONS $DOCKER_NETWORK_OPTIONS $ADD_REGISTRY $BLOCK_REGISTRY $INSECURE_REGISTRY (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 1404 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Aug 23 19:11:17 AY13091717064020986bZ systemd[1]: Starting Docker Application Container Engine...
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ docker-current[1404]: time="2016-08-23T19:11:19.448828158+08:00" level=warning msg="devmapper: Usage of loopback devices is strongly discou...v section."
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ docker-current[1404]: time="2016-08-23T19:11:19.511103592+08:00" level=error msg="[graphdriver] prior storage driver \"devicemapper\" faile...t status 2"
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ docker-current[1404]: time="2016-08-23T19:11:19.511196844+08:00" level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: de...t status 2"
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Hint: Some lines were ellipsized, use -l to show in full.
```

"`journalctl -xe`" output:

```
[root@AY13091717064020986bZ ~]# journalctl -xe
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ kernel: device-mapper: block manager: btree_node validator check failed for block 146
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ kernel: device-mapper: btree spine: node_check failed: csum 1600702373 != wanted 1600827965
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ kernel: device-mapper: block manager: btree_node validator check failed for block 146
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ kernel: Buffer I/O error on device dm-1, logical block 2621424
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ docker-current[1404]: time="2016-08-23T19:11:19.511103592+08:00" level=error msg="[graphdriver] prior storage driver \"devicemapper\" failed: devmapper:
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ docker-current[1404]: time="2016-08-23T19:11:19.511196844+08:00" level=fatal msg="Error starting daemon: error initializing graphdriver: devmapper: Base
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ systemd[1]: docker.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
--
-- The result is failed.
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ systemd[1]: docker.service failed.
Aug 23 19:11:19 AY13091717064020986bZ polkitd[1014]: Unregistered Authentication Agent for unix-process:1370:16052 (system bus name :1.22, object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/Authenticati
Aug 23 19:23:43 AY13091717064020986bZ systemd[1]: Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has begun starting up.
Aug 23 19:23:43 AY13091717064020986bZ systemd[1]: Started Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
-- Subject: Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
--
-- Unit systemd-tmpfiles-clean.service has finished starting up.
--
-- The start-up result is done.
```

Docker version:

```
[root@AY13091717064020986bZ ~]# docker version
Client:
 Version:         1.10.3
 API version:     1.22
 Package version: docker-common-1.10.3-46.el7.centos.10.x86_64
 Go version:      go1.6.3
 Git commit:      d381c64-unsupported
 Built:           Thu Aug  4 13:21:17 2016
 OS/Arch:         linux/amd64
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon. Is the docker daemon running on this host?
```

Linux kernel version:

```
[root@AY13091717064020986bZ ~]# uname -a
Linux AY13091717064020986bZ 3.10.0-327.el7.x86_64 #1 SMP Thu Nov 19 22:10:57 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[root@AY13091717064020986bZ ~]#
```

CentOS version:

```
[root@AY13091717064020986bZ ~]# lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID:    CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.2.1511 (Core)
Release:    7.2.1511
Codename:    Core
[root@AY13091717064020986bZ ~]#
```

Comment: did try to re-install docker?

Comment: can you try to restart the service - service docker restart?

Comment: This problem was not occurred the first time, I removed the /var/lib/docker and re-pulled all images and it worked when it occurred the first time. I could not always do this way, I want to find a method to solve it ultimately. @Bhavesh : output of restart is the same as start.

Answer (score 42, accepted):

I had a similar issue. This was how I fixed it permanently:

- Delete everything in `/var/lib/docker`. This will delete existing container and images:

```
rm -rf /var/lib/docker
```

- Then configure your daemon to use the "overlay" storage driver. Set the following flags in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. If the file doesn't exist, just create it, and add the contents below:

```json
{
    "graph": "/mnt/docker-data",
    "storage-driver": "overlay"
}
```

Now start Docker normally again and all should work fine and always.

See *[Start automatically at system boot](https://docs.docker.com/engine/admin/systemd/#start-automatically-at-system-boot)*.

Comment: Better than overlay is overlay2.

Comment: After I added some entries to /etc/docker/daemon.json as per dockers own page things stopped working for me I ripped them all out and just put  {
    "data-root": "/mnt/docker-data",
    "storage-driver": "overlay"
}

Comment: it solves my problem but I wonder what magic here is? Why remove all in /var/lib/docker work?

Comment: In my case, wrong json formart of `/etc/docker/daemon.json` causes this issue.

Comment: What a bad solution: Cleaning all docker images & containers!!!!

Comment: Error: the "graph" config file option is deprecated; use "data-root" instead.

Comment: Take care with this solution because is dangerous. Read properly before use it "This will delete existing container and images". Make a backup if you choose use it.

Answer (score 137):

Only this command helped me to get the reason of this error:

```
dockerd
```

In the output I saw: *Your Linux kernel version 2.6.32-042stab127.2 is not supported for running docker. Please upgrade your kernel to 3.10.0 or newer.*

Comment: Good way of knowing what's wrong with the daemon. For me it was a permission problem

Comment: thanks, in my case I had to do `sudo service docker start`

Comment: Best answer.  In my case, iptables was not installed and that is why docker was failing to start.

Comment: This post answers a very wider range of docker startup problems. For me, it was a misconfigured bridge interface. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Same here, had to disconnect VPN to install.

Comment: Thanks a lot, best way to find reason

Comment: Thanks. This allowed me to find the real reason and a solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213831/failed-to-start-daemon-error-initializing-network-controller-error-creating-de

Comment: Thanks! Running `dockerd` pointed out to me that I had an illegal `{` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` in which I had two entries for insecure-registies without a comma separating each object. I deleted one object as they were duplicates.

Answer (score 24):

In my case it was empty `daemon.json` file, removing this file fixed it to me:

```bash
sudo rm -f /etc/docker/daemon.json
sudo systemctl start docker
```

Comment: In mycase, the previous developer installed docker v4 on centOS 7, then I tried to install docker-compose. but it said no docker daemon (no docker.service,docker.socket or containerd.service files in system directory) . Even could not restart the docker service, there was no docker service,but basic docker commands worked. Then, I upgraded docker version to latest (v 23). The  every image,container has gone. finally, i tried this answer and it worked.!

Answer (score 15):

### You only need to reboot the server and check if your daemon.json file is correct.

By removing /etc/docker you will loose all Images and data.

you can check logs with

> journalctl -u docker.service

Reboot server

> sudo reboot
>
> systemctl daemon-reload &&
> systemctl enable docker &&
> systemctl start docker

This worked for me.

Comment: It should be `journalctl -u docker.service`, not docker.services though, right?

Answer (score 8):

I had a similar problem with an arch derived. After restarting all went well.

```
sudo shutdown -r now
```

then check with something like

```
systemctl status docker
```

Comment: What is *"arch derived"*?

Comment: Maybe was my English, I mean Arch based, it was Antergos. Like Ubuntu for Debian.
By the way, I remember that when I found the right solution I couldn't believe that it was so simple, just wasting of time.

Comment: Restarting fixed it for me

Comment: Restarting also fixed it for me, in my case it was because I didn't reboot after the previous system upgrade.

Answer (score 5):

You only need delete the containers folder and reboot

```
sudo rm /var/lib/docker/containers/ -rf && sudo reboot
```

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue. This was how I fixed it permanently:

```
mv etc/docker/daemon.json daemon.conf
systemctl daemon-reload
service docker restart
```

Answer (score 2):

Step1. Use 'dockerd' command to check the exact reason

```
[root@c7 docker]# dockerd
INFO[2020-06-03T11:27:50.293740882+05:30] Starting up
INFO[2020-06-03T11:27:50.298500541+05:30] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-06-03T11:27:50.298535150+05:30] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-06-03T11:27:50.298568308+05:30] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2020-06-03T11:27:50.298582671+05:30] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
INFO[2020-06-03T11:27:50.305144487+05:30] parsed scheme: "unix"                         module=grpc
INFO[2020-06-03T11:27:50.305193838+05:30] scheme "unix" not registered, fallback to default scheme  module=grpc
INFO[2020-06-03T11:27:50.305239948+05:30] ccResolverWrapper: sending update to cc: {[{unix:///run/containerd/containerd.sock 0  <nil>}] <nil>}  module=grpc
INFO[2020-06-03T11:27:50.305254274+05:30] ClientConn switching balancer to "pick_first"  module=grpc
failed to start daemon: error initializing graphdriver: /var/lib/docker contains several valid graphdrivers: overlay2, devicemapper; Please cleanup or explicitly choose storage driver (-s <DRIVER>)
```

Step2: remove `overlay` or `devicemapper` storage. Only 1 storage should exist

```
[root@c7 docker]# rm -rf devicemapper
```

Step3: Now start docker
[root@c7 docker]# systemctl start docker

Step4: If you're getting below error

```
[root@c7 docker]# docker container ls
```

Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at `unix:///var/run/docker.sock`. Is the docker daemon running?

Step5: Remove below file and restart docker

```
[root@c7 docker]# rm -rf /var/run/docker.pid
[root@c7 docker]# systemctl restart docker
```

Step6: You'll get back your images and running containers

Answer (score 2):

**dockerd** saved my day, it shown iptables/firewalld missing.
Installed the same and it worked like charm.

Comment: Several other answers already suggest using `dockerd`. Please don't post duplicate answers and/or comments to other answers.

Comment: upvoting because I saw this answer first and it helped me (was issue - iptables not installed)

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, which seems to have been caused by cruft left in `/var/lib/docker` from a previous installation.

**Background details:** I'd briefly used Docker from the CentOS extras repository; I had then removed it, installed the Docker repository, and installed docker-ce from that repository. This left `/var/lib/docker` behind and populated, but not owned by the docker-ce package.

**The following fixed this:**

- `rpm -e docker-ce`
- `rm -f /var/lib/docker`
- `yum install docker-ce`

Answer (score 0):

I've just removed all folders under /var/lib/docker and rebooted the server, that fixed the same problem in a rhel 7.7 system

That happened because I wanted to create a filsystem to be mounted on /var/lib/docker where images are allocated.

****Pay attention that it will also delete all your images, if you want to keep any just issue the docker save command

Answer (score 0):

I was using docker desktop where In the settings I deleted everything in WSL_update_x64. It was not previously installed. So after installing it I deleted the files from the settings and It restarted itself.

Answer (score 0):

I installed these, and the service started:

`sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io docker-compose-plugin`

Answer (score 0):

It works for me:

```
>  sudo update-alternatives --set iptables /usr/sbin/iptables-legacy
```

Answer (score 0):

Inspecting `journalctl -xe` revealed that there was no file such `/usr/bin/dockerd` as this is what the docker daemon is looking for. Strangely enough, `sudo dockerd` was just working fine. Running `sudo which dockerd` indicated that `dockerd` was indeed located at `usr/sbin/dockerd`. Linking `/usr/bin/dockerd` to `/usr/sbin/dockerd` solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue where i was downgrading the docker version. I clean uninstalled and was apt installing a specific version. Just remember to run

`sudo apt update`

Without the above, docker-ce wasn't being installed, which was causing this error

```
Process: 795828 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
```

Ran apt install with the necessary versions i wanted and the docker is back to normal.