# failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, fedora

I'm using `Fedora release 33 (Thirty Three)`
Docker version is `Docker version 20.10.0, build 7287ab3`

First I ran `docker system prune` and since then docker daemon failed to start.

I ran `systemctl start docker` command and got

```
Job for docker.service failed because the control process exited with error code.
See "systemctl status docker.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
```

and then `systemctl status docker.service` I got

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
     Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor pr>
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2020-12-09 11:10:58 IST; 15s >
TriggeredBy: ● docker.socket
       Docs: https://docs.docker.com
    Process: 10391 ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/contai>
   Main PID: 10391 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Dec 09 11:10:58 barad-laptop systemd[1]: docker.service: Scheduled restart job,>
Dec 09 11:10:58 barad-laptop systemd[1]: Stopped Docker Application Container E>
Dec 09 11:10:58 barad-laptop systemd[1]: docker.service: Start request repeated>
Dec 09 11:10:58 barad-laptop systemd[1]: docker.service: Failed with result 'ex>
Dec 09 11:10:58 barad-laptop systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Con>
```

Then `sudo dockerd --debug` and got

```
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: Failed to program NAT chain: ZONE_CONFLICT: 'docker0' already bound to a zone
```

Related to [this Github issue](https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41609)

Comment: related to: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/41609

Answer (score 91, accepted):

Found out that

```
$ firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
FedoraWorkstation
  interfaces: ens4u1u2 wlp59s0
docker
  interfaces: br-48d7d996793a
libvirt
  interfaces: virbr0
trusted
  interfaces: docker0
```

the interface *docker0* seems to be in the *trusted* zone.
But there's another zone called *docker*.

So I decided to give it a shot and add it to the *docker* zone instead.

```
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=docker --change-interface=docker0
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```

Looks like this afterwards:

```
$ firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
FedoraWorkstation
  interfaces: ens4u1u2 wlp59s0
docker
  interfaces: br-48d7d996793a docker0
libvirt
  interfaces: virbr0
```

Seems to work.
Maybe someone can shed more light on this.

**Edit:** added `firewall-cmd --reload` as pointed out in the comments

Comment: get active zones showed me where there was another docker0 binding. thanks!

Comment: I had this error "docker.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'" and this solution worked for me too!

Comment: Brilliant answer. I wish I could up vote you twice. Did you figure out why this problem occurred actually?

Comment: don't forget to `sudo firewall-cmd  --reload`  before checking again

Comment: I would like that the `sudo firewall-cmd  --reload` is added to accepted answer

Happened to me today on Fedora 35

Answer (score 24):

I got this error after upgrading docker-ce on my Fedora 32. It looks like the new docker conflicts with the manual firewall configuration mentioned in [the article](https://fedoramagazine.org/docker-and-fedora-32/) you linked in your answer. I had the rules on my machine to enable container-to-container communication.

Docker started successfully after I reverted the firewall rules:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --remove-interface=docker0
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=FedoraWorkstation --remove-masquerade
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
sudo systemctl restart docker
```

The changes don't seem to affect the ability of containers to talk to each other.

Comment: Just had the same problem after upgrading to Fedora 33 and this solution worked. I did have to re-apply the rules afterwards for the docker containers to have network access again.

Comment: @Quintesse thanks for the info. Does the docker service start successfully after a reboot? It won't start on my Fedora 32 with either of these rules in place. Also, what do you mean by network access?

Comment: I used `firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --remove-interface=docker0` and it fixed my problem

Answer (score 2):

With a similar problem, I removed `docker0` from the trusted zone, reload the firewall, and also removed `daemon.json` from `/etc/docker`

```
sudo firewall-cmd --get-active-zones

sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=trusted --remove-interface=docker0
sudo firewall-cmd --reload

sudo rm -rf /etc/docker/daemon.json # or mv to another location
```

Then restart docker service with `sudo systemctl restart docker`.