# Failed to start docker-daemon: Firewalld: docker zone already exists

Tags: docker-daemon

I have the following after running `firewall-cmd --get-active-zones`

```
public
  interfaces: virbr0 docker0 lxcbr0 wlan0
trusted
  sources: 172.17.0.0/16 53.0.0.0/8
```

These are insights I got from [failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65213831/failed-to-start-daemon-error-initializing-network-controller-error-creating-de)

The problem is, `sudo dockerd` fails with error messages, among which there is

```
failed to start daemon: Error initializing network controller: Error creating default "bridge" network: Failed to program NAT chain: ZONE_CONFLICT: 'docker0' already bound to a zone
```

How to manipulate the zone so that I can start the docker daemon?

EDIT: This solution worked for me:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=docker 
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=docker --add-interface=docker0
```

Answer (score 3):

this works (do all the steps):

1. Check if docker zone exists in firewall-cmd

```bash
$ firewall-cmd --get-active-zones
```

2. If "docker" zone is available, change interface to docker0 (not persisted)

```bash
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=docker --change-interface=docker0
```

3. If "docker" zone is available, change interface to docker0 (persisted, thanks [rbjorklin](https://gist.github.com/rbjorklin))

```bash
$ sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=docker --change-interface=docker0
$ sudo systemctl restart firewalld
```

credit: https://gist.github.com/reytech-dev/1cbbb158df374018be454537de32a428

Answer (score 0):

it was better to mention the solution in answers @Ilonpilaaja.
this commands worked for me too:

```
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --new-zone=docker 
sudo firewall-cmd --reload
sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=docker --add-interface=docker0
```