# docker service fails when started

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel

I'm on an AWS EC2 instance and I'm trying to install docker on the instance.

i first run `sudo yum update -y` and then `sudo yum install -y docker`

but then i tried to start the docker service using `sudo service docker start` i got the error below:

```
Redirecting to /bin/systemctl start docker.service
```

[image]

i ran `dockerd` cammand and i got this which seems like everything is fine:
[image]

i have no clue whatsoever what could be the cause of this! i tried many possible solutions such as these [Docker service start failed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39100641/docker-service-start-failed) but it was to no avail!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you had installed docker-daemon mode, not docker service.

Remove old versions

```
sudo yum remove docker \
                  docker-client \
                  docker-client-latest \
                  docker-common \
                  docker-latest \
                  docker-latest-logrotate \
                  docker-logrotate \
                  docker-engine
```

`sudo yum install -y yum-utils`

```
sudo yum-config-manager \
    --add-repo \
    https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
```

`sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io`

`sudo systemctl start docker`

Docker has a great documentation, please always refer them. [For centOS](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/centos/)

Edit :
If you have rhel-7 you may get

> error failure: repodata/repomd.xml from docker-ce-stable: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

```
sudo yum remove docker docker-common docker-selinux docker-engine-selinux docker-engine docker-ce
sudo yum install -y yum-utils device-mapper-persistent-data lvm2
sudo yum-config-manager --add-repo https://download.docker.com/linux/centos/docker-ce.repo
sudo yum install docker-ce
```

If the error persists, enable the repository by running the following command ~~~
[Redhat discussion](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/5336741)

`yum-config-manager --enable REPOSITORY yum install docker`

Comment: thanks for answering, when i tried to run sudo yum install docker-ce docker-ce-cli containerd.io, it throws an error failure: repodata/repomd.xml from docker-ce-stable: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.

Comment: @Ebdulmomen20 Do you have rhel7?

Comment: @Ebdulmomen20 Please check updated answer